# Android, Add specific web page in webview cache database

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to add specific web page in webview's cache database?

Comment: What do you mean? Injecting an arbitrary page content to the cache that would load on entering that URL?

Comment: I want...
Advance, Download to special page(url) to cache database.
And when offline, Displaying with cache page.

Comment: I believe the best option might be to download that page to a local file and to redirect to that local file when offline.

Comment: Thanks.
Maybe I Seems to have found a way.
using hash, Check the page exists.
If the page is not exists, call loadUrl("page URL").
Then, Maybe WebView will download the page, and save to cache.
Can I do this?